# My user Session changes on every profile page

Tags: php, sql

I have a friend_system that has multiple users. (obviously)  However, whenever a logged in user opens up another users page, the other user is automatically logged in.  For example if I am logged in as user 1 and visit user 2's page, I am automatically logged out of user 1 and logged back in as user 2.  I think it has something to do with this script:

```
if(isset($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['user'])) {
    $user = $_GET['user'];
} else {
  $user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
}
```

Then I verified this with a standard sql script to echo the username of the corresponding user.  I have player around with this script a little and the most change I saw was when I had every users profile page be the same as the user that was logged in.  Please help me with this, I have checked all over the internet and still can't find an answer.

Comment: are you calling `session_start`?

Comment: you should also not just blindly trust `$_GET` for a user.

Comment: The session start is before this script.  I just didn't feel it was neccessary to put the entire page of code for this small thing.

Comment: How else could I perform this function without GET